# Creating Ratio with attributes of different dimensions

Tags: tableau-api

I'm pretty new at Tableau and really struggling to create ratios of dimension attributes. In Excel it's so easy to do that. ;-).

I'm trying to get the ratio of

(MRR+MRE+MRA)/Authorisations

and then display that as a percentage. I would like to use Time and Geo as dimensions to filter by. Really would appreciate some hints.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sounds like you just need a calculated field:

1. right-lick in the "measures" section
2. choose "create/calculated field"
3. In the opened window use your furmola to calculate the ratio `([MRR]+[MRE+MRA])/[Authorisations]`. Call it `Ratio` and click OK
4. Right click on the `Ratio` pill in the measures pane and go to "Default Properties/ Number Format/ Percentage"

For the filter you just drag your dimensions to the "Filter" pane and chooses whichever values you need

Comment: If you use a row level calc like this, you then have to determine the aggregation for it (e.g. sum, avg, min, max, etc) when you place the field on a Tableau viz. Be sure the aggregation computes what you think it does. Calculating the sum of a set of ratios is seldom what you want. If you want the ratio applied after aggregating row values, you can create an aggregate calculation instead by specifying the aggregation function inside the formula at the point you wish it performed.

Comment: @alex you are right. I actually interpreted it as being on a row level, for a lack of further information. After reading your comment I see that it might have been meant to be aggregated somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to create an **aggregate** calculation, such as `SUM(MRR + MRE + MRA) / SUM(Authorisations)`

The aggregate functions you choose depend on your goal. Choices include min, max, avg, count, etc, see the docs

An aggregate calc is computed for each block of data rows that share the same dimension values, unlike a row level calc that is computed for each individual row.

Usually ratios are a hint to consider an aggregate calculation.